# Does Spokestack support React-Native?

Tags: react-native, voice, voiceover, spokestack

I see the React-Native library hasn't been updated lately? https://github.com/spokestack/react-native-spokestack

Is it still being supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2.1.2 version is still supported! There will be a 3.0 soon™ with Text to Speech support and other shiny new features TBD.